# 14.04 only stable in recovery mode

Tags: graphics

Problem is that if loaded "normally" it gets to the desktop screen and then blacks out.  I have tried many of the suggested fixes on the net but to no avail and my system is only stable when I start it in recovery mode and then it's fine.  I am not a linux expert, just a competent Ubuntu user for many years.  System is running VESA: Intel(r)Q33/Q35/G33 Graphics.  Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why, but I will show what I did and solved the problem:

1. Start Additional Drivers Application
2. Check NVIDIA legacy binary driver version 304.117 from nvidia-304 (proprietary, tested) button.
3. Restart

and that's OK!

Comment: The nVidia driver is definitely not going to help with OP's Intel graphics adapter, but using `jockey` (the “additional drivers application”) is a good idea.